# How to exclude results with get_object_or_404?

Tags: python, django, orm

In Django you can use the exclude to create SQL similar to `not equal`. An example could be.

```
Model.objects.exclude(status='deleted')
```

Now this works great and exclude is very flexible. Since I'm a bit lazy, I would like to get that functionality when using `get_object_or_404`, but I haven't found a way to do this, since you cannot use exclude on `get_object_or_404`.

What I want is to do something like this:

```
model = get_object_or_404(pk=id, status__exclude='deleted')
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work as there isn't an exclude query filter or similar. The best I've come up with so far is doing something like this:

```
object = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
if object.status == 'deleted':
    return HttpResponseNotfound('text')
```

Doing something like that, really defeats the point of using `get_object_or_404`, since it no longer is a handy one-liner.

Alternatively I could do:

```
object = get_object_or_404(pk=id, status__in=['list', 'of', 'items'])
```

But that wouldn't be very maintainable, as I would need to keep the list up to date.

I'm wondering if I'm missing some trick or feature in django to use `get_object_or_404` to get the desired result?

Comment: It's not really an answer, but it seems like you wouldn't actually want to 404 for a soft deleted object. The whole point of soft deletion is to keep the object around "just in case".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`django.db.models.Q`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

model = get_object_or_404(MyModel, ~Q(status='deleted'), pk=id)
```

The Q objects lets you do NOT (with `~` operator) and OR (with `|` operator) in addition to AND.

Note that the Q object must come before `pk=id`, because keyword arguments must come last in Python.

Comment: Of cause the Q object. Didn't know it would work in that contest. Thanx.

Comment: Aside from a Model, you can also pass a Manager or a QuerySet as the first parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476339/336694

Answer (score 15):

The most common use case is to pass a Model. However, you can also pass a QuerySet instance:

```
queryset = Model.objects.exclude(status='deleted')
get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=1)
```

Django docs example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2

Comment: I think this is an easier to follow solution than the accepted answer. I mean if I'm looking over my code from 6 months ago, I would want to punch myself in the face if I used a Q object instead of filtering with an exclude.

Comment: I agree. Q should only be used for complex queries. Your solution is much more readable for junior Django devs.

Comment: Best solution imho

Answer (score 1):

There's another way instead of using Q objects. Instead of passing the model to `get_object_or_404` just pass the QuerySet to the function instead:

`model = get_object_or_404(MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id).exclude(status='deleted'))`

One side effect of this, however, is that it will raise a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception if the QuerySet returns multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_or_404` utilizes the `get_queryset` method of the object manager.  If you override the `get_queryset` method to only return items that aren't "deleted" then `get_object_or_404` will automatically behave as you want.  However, overriding `get_queryset` like this will likely have issues elsewhere (perhaps in the admin pages), but you could add an alternate manager for when you need to access the soft deleted items.

```
from django.db import models

class ModelManger(models.Manger):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ModelManger, self).get_queryset().exclude(status='deleted')

class Model(models.Model):
    # ... model properties here ...

    objects = ModelManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

So if you need only non-deleted items you can do `get_object_or_404(Models, id=id)` but if you need all items you can do `get_object_or_404(Models.all_objects, id=id)`.