# Django TypeError get_object_or_404() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django

I'm making a blog and learning django as I go. I'm trying to incorporate urls that include both sluglines and post ids.

When I click on the "view on site" link in the admin panel, I get this error:
NoReverseMatch at /admin/r/7/2/ Reverse for 'article' with arguments '(u'test-post-3', '2')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

When I manually enter the url, I get this error:
TypeError at /articles/test-post-3,2/ get_object_or_404() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
Here's my code:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.

from articles.models import Content

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'articles/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_articles_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Content.objects.filter(
            published_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-published_date')[:5]

def detail(request, slugline, id):
    article = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': article})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from articles import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
    #url(r'^(?P<slugline>[-\w\d]+), (?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
    url(r'^(?P<slugline>[-\w\d]+),(?P<id>\d+)/$', view=views.detail, name='article'),
)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.


class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slugline = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return ('article', (), {
            # 'slugline': self.slugline,
            # 'id': self.id,
        # })
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('article', args=[self.slugline, str(self.id)])

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.published_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'published_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'the_Bluntist.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls', namespace="articles")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad usage of `get_object_or_404`:

> Docstring:
>   `get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs)`
>   Uses `get()` to return an object, or raises a `Http404` exception if the object
>   does not exist.
>   
> `klass` may be a `Model`, `Manager`, or `QuerySet` object. All other passed
>   arguments and keyword arguments are used in the `get()` query.
>   
>   Note: Like with `get()`, an `MultipleObjectsReturned` will be raised if more than one
>   object is found.

You can make as following:

- `article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)`
- `article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects, pk=id))`
- `article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(), pk=id))`
- `article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.filter(pk=id))`

Answer (score 0):

```
article = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
```

You must pass the model *and* the filter to the call. [Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

```
article = get_object_or_404(klass, pk=id)
```